# Java/Android which coding method is preferred?

Tags: java, android

As a self taught coder I have a question about coding best practice. I have written the same program in two different ways, and I would like someone to give me the guidance on which way is preferred? This might be from a CPU overhead or RAM usage or simply a coding best practice perspective. I appreciate there may be many answers or theories to this question, and I know that isn't what Stack Overflow is here for, but to me this is a Stack Overflow question as my coding style is causing me some problems and I don't know which method I should be either sticking too or adopting.

Both examples have a simple XML layout file with two buttons and two updatable textviews (not included here).

Example 1. (the way I tend to code at the moment)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1Add, button2Add;
    TextView text1Display, text2Display;
    int count1, count2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initilizeButtons();
        setupListeners();
    }

    public void initilizeButtons() {
        button1Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        text1Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        count1 = Integer.parseInt(text1Display.getText().toString());
        count2 = Integer.parseInt(text2Display.getText().toString());
    }

    public void setupListeners() {
        button1Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                count1++;
                text1Display.setText(String.valueOf(count1));
            }
        });

        button2Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                count2++;
                text2Display.setText(String.valueOf(count2));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Example 2. (the way I think I should be coding?)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initilizeButtons();

    }

    public void initilizeButtons() {
        Button button1Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TextView text1Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                int headCount = Integer.parseInt(text1Display.getText().toString());
                headCount++;
                text1Display.setText(String.valueOf(headCount));
            }

        });

        button2Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                TextView text2Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                int bodyCount = Integer.parseInt(text2Display.getText().toString());
                bodyCount++;
                text2Display.setText(String.valueOf(bodyCount));
            }

        });
    }

}
```

In example 1 I assume this will be quicker (i.e. less CPU) as I've declared my variables and just add to them throughout the programme. I'm worried here about RAM usage.

In example 2 I think this will cause more CPU usage as it has to redeclare all the variables each time they are used, but maybe it uses less RAM?

These are simply examples, and I'm sure they themselves will not cause much in the way of CPU or RAM overheads. I will apply the information from the answer you supply to my general coding practice.

Comment: Do you have a performance/memory issue? If not, then remember: `premature optimization is the root of all evil...` By the way having a reference is not considered a memory cost these days. Having too many references (and not maintaining them properly) on the other hand might lead to memory leak...

Comment: You might want to repost to codereview.stackexchange.com. These are the kinds of questions they focus on.

Comment: what do you want to know with your question. please clearify your question first, so that other could replied you best.

Comment: But in this case, as you said - the first example is better. And an advice: you should avoid creating objects in loops or methods that are called in loops/frequently (like onDraw() or getView()) because it generates garbage.

Comment: Declaring one extra Integer, or 500 integers, or 100 buttons, or adding two small if statements to a loop of 10000 iterations, or so, have a very negligible effects on average computer today. You should not worry about these things prematurely. What you should strive for is `readable` code. Definitely, you should worry about memory and processing at `some` level, but that is far far far from declaring two more buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think example 1 should be the preferred way.

The Ram usage does not increase much, as the Widgets are existing if you use findViewById or not. You only get a reference to the objects shown.

Personally i use [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) this allows you to drop the `initilizeButtons()` as you can add some Annotations to the fields and the library injects them for you. Look at thier code comparison on thier website... its awesome. And it also supports many other nice features. And the best part is, that it uses Code generation and not use runtime reflection(what costs cpu and performance) like other similar librarys...

Comment: Also thanks for the link, looks like a good library.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on your need,

in example if your Activity use many times with that Views, option 2 is better

Answer (score 0):

Might not be helping, but I actually personally hate both options. In an activity with a complex layout, it will have you repeating the onclick method code time and time again.

Consider this; (sorry if there are any typos, did it in notepad). 
I did not focus on the rest of the code, such as naming a method 'initilizeButtons' which is incorrect spelling, plus misleading since you're not only **initializing** buttons, but also textviews and integers.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button button1Add, button2Add;
    TextView text1Display, text2Display;
    int count1, count2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initilizeButtons();
        setupListeners();
    }

    public void initilizeButtons() {
        button1Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        text1Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text2Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        count1 = Integer.parseInt(text1Display.getText().toString());
        count2 = Integer.parseInt(text2Display.getText().toString());
    }

    public void setupListeners() {
        button1Add.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2Add.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       switch(view.getId()){     
         case R.id.button1:
            // Do your button1 things
         break;
         case R.id.button2:
            // do your button2 things
         break; 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory and performance wise I see no obvious difference. In general it is advisable to keep scope of declared variables as small as possible. So if in the rest of your activities you don't need the buttons anymore don't declare them as fields in your class.

My personal experience is that using many anonymous inner classes makes code hard to read, so either go for the activity implementing the interface, or make small named inner classes in your enclosing activity.